# What is Bow Distract Range?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

[This rune](http://shadowofmordor.wikia.com/wiki/Foresight) increases "bow distract range", but I can't find what that means. Is that the range at which you can cause an orc to come investigate with Right Trigger and Y (or R2 and Triangle)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bow distract range refers to the "distract" function of the bow (LT and Y). It functions similarly to stealth attract, except in reverse; nearby Uruks are drawn to investigate the spot that you aim at when using distract.

There is a [similar rune](http://shadowofmordor.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter%27s_Instinct) that increases stealth attract range.